# how to shuffle a list if i have order is not as much as list

Tags: python-3.x, shuffle

I want to shuffle the list with function shuffle_order,
this is my code:

```
def shuffle_order(txt,order):
    return ''.join([txt[i] for i in order])


print(shuffle_order(['abcd','ienf','dfjs'],[2,1,3,0]))
```

I want the result to look like this `['cbda','nefi','jfsd']`

Comment: Your list has 3 items while order list has 4. Why?

Comment: I'm learning to make encryption right now, I have a code where the lists must be shuffled if only have 4 orders.
Is it possible to shuffle the list using 4 orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to reorder every string in your list according to your order list you provided. You can try this:

```
def reorder_str(s, order):
    return ''.join([s[i] for i in order])


def encrypt_lst(lst, order):
    return [reorder_str(s, order) for s in lst]


print(encrypt_lst(['abcd', 'ienf', 'dfjs'], [2, 1, 3, 0]))
```

```
['cbda', 'nefi', 'jfsd']
```